# GitHub Actions for PHPUnit is failing

Tags: php, laravel, github, phpunit, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions to run PHP CS Fixer and PHPUnit for each pull request created. I implemented this GitHub Action for PHPUnit and my YML file is as follows.

```
name: PHPUnit Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  build-test:
    name: PHPUnit Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: php-actions/composer@v5
        with:
          php_extensions: mailparse pdo_mysql
          dev: no
          args: --profile --ignore-platform-reqs

      - name: PHPUnit Tests
        uses: php-actions/phpunit@v3
        with:
          php_version: 8.1
```

I am having below error from PHPUnit Action.

```
994393dc58e7: Layer already exists
1e74372f6dff: Pushed
php-latest-mailparse-pdo_mysql-build2: digest: sha256:17078db8c8e36a72ce937d8b5f98eb0c0b814b91a2c20e14788039763b722300 size: 2831
Docker tag: docker.pkg.github.com/synega/connect/php-actions_composer_connect:php-latest-mailparse-pdo_mysql-build2
No private keys supplied
Command: composer install --no-dev --no-progress --no-interaction --profile --ignore-platform-reqs
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How/where i can get private keys for `mailparse`? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to add `ACTION_SSH_KEY` in github secrets for your project. It is required for private repositories.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/composer-php-actions#passing-arguments

Comment: https://github.com/php-actions/example-composer/blob/master/.github/workflows/composer-v4.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't `mailparse` specifically that needs the private key, it's the project as a whole - private repositories need to use SSH authentication - see the [composer-php-actions manual](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/composer-php-actions#installing-private-repositories):

> To install from a private repository, SSH authentication must be used. Generate an SSH key pair for this purpose and add it to your private repository's configuration, preferable with only read-only privileges. On Github for instance, this can be done by using deploy keys.
>
> Add the key pair to your project using Github Secrets, and pass them into the php-actions/composer action by using the ssh_key and ssh_key_pub inputs. If your private repository is stored on another server than github.com, you also need to pass the domain via ssh_domain.
>
> Example yaml, showing how to pass secrets:
>
> ```
> jobs:
>   build:
>
>     ...
>
>     - name: Install dependencies
>       uses: php-actions/composer@v6
>       with:
>         ssh_key: ${{ secrets.ssh_key }}
>         ssh_key_pub: ${{ secrets.ssh_key_pub }}
> ```
>
> There is an example repository available for reference at https://github.com/php-actions/example-composer that uses a private dependency. Check it out for a live working project.

The documentation on [Github Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets) walks through how to create them for Github.

Comment: Hi, i will try to follow your answer and will come back ASAP. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Your suggestion solved the problem, thanks a lot for the help. :)